# how to make this mysql join faster

Tags: mysql

mysql 5.7.17

```
create temporary table tmp(_ip INT UNSIGNED primary key) engine = myisam

CREATE TABLE `t_rep` (
  `_ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `_timeInsert` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `_timeUpdate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `_other1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `_other2` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `_other3` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `_subRatting` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `_other4` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `_other5` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `_other6` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `_other7` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `_other8` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_ip`),
  KEY `ix_cb1` (`_ip`,`_timeInsert`,`_timeUpdate`,`_subRatting`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (_ip DIV 256 % 256 % 10)
(PARTITION part0 VALUES LESS THAN (1) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION part1 VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION part2 VALUES LESS THAN (3) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION part3 VALUES LESS THAN (4) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION part4 VALUES LESS THAN (5) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION part5 VALUES LESS THAN (6) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION part6 VALUES LESS THAN (7) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION part7 VALUES LESS THAN (8) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION part8 VALUES LESS THAN (9) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION part9 VALUES LESS THAN (10) ENGINE = MyISAM) */
```

table tmp has ~10M records;
table t_repu has ~ 1B records;

```
select count(*) from tmp as a
    inner join t_rep as b 
      on b._ip = a._ip 
     and b._timeInsert < unix_timestamp('2016-03-01')
     and b._timeUpdate < unix_timestamp('2016-03-01')
     and b._subRatting <= 4;
```

Questions: 
1. why I can not use index t_rep.ix_cb1 ?
2. I have to set primary key for table tmp ?
3. How to make it runs faster ?

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, a, , index, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, , 18878329, 100.00, Using index
1, SIMPLE, b, part0~9, eq_ref, PRIMARY,ix_cb1, PRIMARY, 4, a._ip, 1, 5.00, Using where
```

Comment: Have you run `EXPLAIN` on your query?  Joining 10M records to 1B could take some time, even with indices setup.

Comment: I explained, the problem is the index can not be used, scanned whole table, even if I only filled million records to each table, it also runs endless.

Comment: If you post EXPLAIN results we may be able to help yo understand WHY the index is not used.

Comment: What is the % of records in t_rep that have _subRatting = 4?

Comment: Please see explain below, and there is 17% records that _subRatting <= 4.

Comment: Great - I suggest to add an index on _subRatting only or an index that starts with _subRatting and also has the timestamps. Then filtering of the t_rep records could use this index well, while joining to the tmp table will use the primary keys

Comment: @Galz, @Solarflare Got it. tried to add `index _subRatting`. no change.
try add `force index ix_cb1`.  finish in 40 secs of 10% record.  
works endless if without `force index ix_cb1`.

Comment: New question. query finish in 40 secs of 10% of `t_rep`, but endless for whole `t_rep`. could someone know something about it ?

Comment: What do you mean endless? Time will *not really be linear*, but if 10% takes 40 minutes then the whole query can run for 400 minutes... Did you wait that long?

Comment: I wait for 20 minutes. and give up.
now, I am trying to build temp table that cache the filtered data.
right now, the question is two table for 1 column inner join.
one has 111M records with index. another has 200M records without index.
it still runs endless...

Comment: A quick estimate: assuming a 75% page fill rate and a hdd with 40mb/s (which you probably cannot fully use and might in practice be a factor 10 lower depending on your os settings), assuming random ip distribution in `tmp` and 17% of rows with `_subRatting <= 4`, the `ix_cbx1`-index should need about 440s (so 40sec for 10% sounds reasonable) and an index on `(_subRatting,_timeInsert,_timeUpdate)` should require about 70s. An ssd and a lot of ram for your key index (your server should probably have about 64gb+ ram and MySQL should be configured to use it) could improve it a lot.

Comment: Thanks very much every body.